# Buscar valor específico dentro de um arquivo .txt C#

Tags: c#, linq, txt

Tenho um arquivo .txt com as seguintes linhas:

```
000-000 = CRT
001-000 = 00000021
009-000 = 00
012-000 = 247823
013-000 = 0000559877
022-000 = 24082017
023-000 = 152842
032-000 = 80F1
100-000 = JORGE EXPEDITO      
307-000 = S17SNSNNNSPSS9MSNN00
308-000 = CLIENTE TESTE - APENAS MEDICAMENTOS. DEVE SER APRESENTADA RECEITA 
MEDICA EM MESMO NOME DO CARTAO. PODE HAVER COBRANCA DE VALOR A VISTA.
370-000 = CONSULT CLIENTE-CARTAO   
999-999 =
```

Preciso pegar o valor do parâmetro 001-000 = ... que está dentro do arquivo. Alguma idéia de como fazer isso no C# pensei em algo com LINQ mas não sei como implementar, alguma ideia?

Comment: na linha `308-000` tem quebra de linha ou é apenas uma linha ?

Comment: é apenas uma linha mesmo!

Comment: O que vc já fez até agora? Compartilha o código.

Comment: Você pode fazer um leitura de arquivo e verificar se a linha contém o que procura... de qualquer forma você precisará carregar o conteúdo do arquivo no C#

Comment: sim a questão é que tenho que verificar o valor depois do sinal de igual = do parâmetro 001-000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente, é isso:

```
var valores = File.ReadAllLines("NomeDoArquivo.txt")
                  .Where(l => l.StartsWith("001-000"))
                  .Select(l => l.Substring(l.LastIndexOf("=") + 1))
                  .ToList();
```

O uso seria

```
foreach(var valor in results)
    Console.WriteLine(valor);
```

`File.ReadAllLines` retorna um array de string com todas as linhas do arquivo.

O `Where` é o filtro, ele diz: "Para cada linha do arquivo, me devolva apenas aquelas que iniciem com **`001-000`**.

O `Select` vai ser sobre a coleção produzida pelo `Where`, ou seja, apenas as linhas que iniciarem com **`001-000`**. E para item desta coleção, será selecionada a sua `substring` partindo do *index* do símbolo de igualdade (**`=`**), que é o seu separador de chaves e valores.

Isso irá produzir uma lista com os resultados, se tiver **absoluta certeza** de que sempre haverá um espaço entre o sinal de igual e o valor, pode trocar o **+1** do `Select` por **+2**.

Comment: Como eu disse, Sidnei, isso produz uma **lista** com os resultados. Tente capturar a posição 0 do seu resultado (`valor[0]`).

Comment: fiz aqui rapidão e mandei exibir o retorno porém exibiu essa mensagem no console: 
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.String]

Comment: Obviamente é possível adaptar o código pra produzir só um resultado, mas como o gasto é o mesmo, deixei retornando uma lista

Comment: Opa consegui aqui. Ptz muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode manter uma List<> com todos os parâmetros, e quando precisar, buscar o valor necessário. Fiz um exemplo:

Classe Parametro:

```
public class Parametro
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Valor { get; set; }

    public static List<Parametro> CarregarParametros()
    {
        List<Parametro> lista = new List<Parametro>();

        TextReader tr = new StreamReader("C:\\parametros.txt", Encoding.Default);
        string linha = "";
        while ((linha = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!linha.StartsWith("*")) //parâmetro comentado ?!
            {
                string[] value = linha.Split('=');
                lista.Add(new Parametro() { Id = value[0].Trim(), Valor = value[1].Trim() });
            }
        }

        return lista;
    }

}
```

Carregando a lista e buscando um valor:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Parametro> parametros = Parametro.CarregarParametros();

        string valor001 = parametros.Single(p => p.Id == "001-000").Valor;
    }
```

Comment: Opa essa é uma boa ideia também já tava pensando em algo genérico assim também. Isso me ajuda muito também. Obrigado!